# Why is this infinte loop happening?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, infinite-loop

Guys I really need some help here :(

I need to create a contact list in which I need to be able to create, edit, delete, show and search contacts.

But after I enter number 1 (to include a new number) and type the name and number, it goes to an infinite loop and I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out why it's happening and how to fix it.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this block at the end of the code:

```
while (op!=6)
System.out.println();
```

But when I remove it, the loop just doesn't happen. Instead of an infinite loop it just doesn't loop at all. I've been trying for literally hours now and I can't seem to figure it out at all.
(also I'm not allowed to use array list here)

Sorry for my english and thank you already!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vetor45 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] name = new String[1000];
        String nname, auxname;
        int[] tel = new int[1000];
        int ntel, op, cont, i, k, auxtel;

        cont = 0;
        k = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            name[i] = "Empty";
            tel[i] = 0;
        }

        {

            System.out.println("contact list:");
            System.out.println("1. include a new number");
            System.out.println("2. edit a number");
            System.out.println("3. delete a number");
            System.out.println("4. print all numbers");
            System.out.println("5. search by name");
            System.out.println("6. exit");
            System.out.println("Option:");

            op = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("");

            if (op == 1) {
                if (k <= 999) {
                    while (name[k] != "Empty") {
                        k++;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Enter a name:");
                    name[k] = scanner.next();

                    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
                    tel[k] = scanner.nextInt();
                    k++;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("complete");
                }
            }

            else {
                if (op == 2) {
                    i = 0;
                    System.out.println("enter a name:");
                    nname = scanner.next();

                    while (nname != name[i] && i < k - 1) {
                        i++;
                    }

                    if (nname == name[i]) {
                        System.out.println("enter the new number:");
                        ntel = scanner.nextInt();
                        tel[i] = ntel;
                    }

                    else {
                        System.out.println("name not registred");
                    }

                }

                else {
                    if (op == 3) {
                        k--;
                        i = 0;
                        System.out.println("enter a name:");
                        nname = scanner.next();

                        while (nname != name[i] && i < k) {
                            i++;
                        }

                        if (nname == name[i]) {
                            name[i] = "Empty";
                            tel[i] = 0;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("name not registred");
                        }

                    }

                    else {

                        if (op == 4) {
                            for (i = 0; i <= k - 2; i++) {
                                for (cont = i + 1; cont <= k - 1; cont++) {
                                    if (name[i] == name[cont]) {
                                        auxname = name[i];
                                        name[i] = name[cont];
                                        name[cont] = auxname;
                                        auxtel = tel[i];
                                        tel[i] = tel[cont];
                                        tel[cont] = auxtel;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            System.out.println("phone list:");
                            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                                if (name[i] != "Empty") {
                                    System.out.println("name: " + name[i]);
                                    System.out.println("tel: " + tel[i]);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            if (op == 5) {
                                i = 0;
                                System.out.println("enter a name:");
                                nname = scanner.next();
                                while (nname != name[i] && i < k) {
                                    i++;
                                }

                                if (nname == name[i]) {
                                    System.out.println("name: " + nname);
                                    System.out.println("Tel: " + tel);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("name not registred");
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (op == 6) {
                                    System.out.println("exiting");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("option not available");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        while (op != 6)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (op!=6)` is the infinite loop, since `op` doesn't change inside it, and thus can't become `6`. You need to check whether `i` changes in the way you want it to, and does not get unintentionally set to `1000` or more within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even have a do/while loop in this code, here is what a do/while loop loops like:

```
  do{
     //loop
  }while(op != 6); //don't forget semi colon
```

You need to develop some standard for braces, and such. As it is right now, it's really hards to read this code.

Comment: I'm sorry it's confusing. I'm new to this and not very good. and also that was super helpful! thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as surmised by both you and @Amadan, the `while (op != 6)` is the problem. In general, when you're looping, something in the loop has to modify something in the condition you're looping on or something in the loop has to modify the normal control flow (so a `return`, `break`, etc.), so when you see `while (op != 6)`, you should think "`op` is the only variable in the condition, so something inside the loop has to modify `op` or there has to be some other way to get out of the loop."

I think what you want to do is put a `do` before the big block before the while and then have the `while` at the end of the block, so you're doing this:

```
do
{
    ...
    op = scanner.nextInt();
    ...
} while (op != 6);
```

That will read an `int` into `op`, do some stuff with it, and then bail out if the user entered 6.

Comment: i'll try it right now. thanks a lot a man. that's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The loop `while (op!=6)` is being run without any changes to `op` being allowed inside it.

```
//Rest of the code
    System.out.println();
}

while (op!=6)
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

The loop should be evealuated at the beginning of what you need to execute and have everything you want to do in the loop (including changing `op`) inside it:

```
for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{name[i]="Empty"; tel[i]=0;}
while (op!=6)
{
System.out.println("contact list:");
//Rest of the code
```

You will probably have to move some braces round when you do this also. But I'm not going to go through the whole thing/ that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: With the code given, that won't even compile because `op` isn't initialized. If the declaration of `op` is something like `int op = -1;`, then having the while before will work.